# как поменять стилевые свойства только у элементов списка где есть "http" через js

Tags: javascript, события, link

```
<div class="block">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="index.html">index.html</a></li>
               <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
               <li><a href="http://itstep.by">http://itstep.by</a></li>
               <li><a href="local/path">local/path</a></li>
               <li><a href="http://mustat.itstep.org">http://mustat.itstep.org</a>ства </li>
            </ul>
         </div>


let links = document.querySelectorAll('ul a:not([href^="http"])');
console.log(links);
links.forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.borderBottom = '1px solid black';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы задать стили ссылкам содержащим http:// `a[href*="http://"] {}`

Чтобы задать стили ссылкам начинающимся на http:// `a[href^="http://"] {}`

Пример css и js:

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('ul a[href*="http://"]');
console.log(links);
links.forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.borderBottom = '1px solid black';
});
```

```css
a[href*="http://"] {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">index.html</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://itstep.by">http://itstep.by</a></li>
    <li><a href="local/path">local/path</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mustat.itstep.org">http://mustat.itstep.org</a>ства </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Подробнее про селектор атрибута почитать тут...](https://html5book.ru/osnovy-css/)